# How to use async/await in Angular/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a Trip object:

```
{  "id": "1",  "country":"UK",  "city": "London"  }
```

I'm trying to create an edit form, where the form gets populated with the values from the trip object. I'm able to populate the countries dropdown (in `ngOnInit()`), and the selected country has a binding to `trip.country`. But I'm not able to fetch the cities of that country, because apparently the `trip` is still `undefined` when it is supposed to get `trip.country` to find the cities of that country. (I try to print the trip, and get undefined)

I tried using async with the `getTrip()` function, but I get the error that:

> Error:(71, 21) TS1055:Type 'void' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

I think the solution is some kind of async/await/promise strategy but I can't get hold of it.

```
export class TripEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  trip;
  countries;
  cities;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getTrip();
    this.countries = this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe(
        data => { this.countries = data;},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done loading countries')
    );
    console.log("this trip: ", this.trip) //this is undefined

    this.cities = this.cityService.getCitiesByCountry(this.trip.country).subscribe(
        data => { this.cities = data; },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('done loading cities') );
     }

getTrip(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.tripService.getTrip(id).subscribe(trip => { this.trip = trip;  });
    } else {
      this.trip = new Trip();
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
getTrip(): Promise{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
            if (id) {
                this.tripService.getTrip(id).subscribe(
                trip => { 
                    this.trip = trip;
                    resolve();
               },
               error=>reject(error)
             );
            }
            else {
                this.trip = new Trip();
                resolve();
            }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
this.getTrip().then(()=>{
    /*your callback here*/
})
.catch(error=>{
    /*catch exception here*/
})
```

If you want to use async/await, make sure that you in you compilerOptions (tsconfig.json) field "target" has "ES6" value

Comment: @ДмитрийНикифоров Thank you. I have just noticed, however, that the json file for cities is very huge and it is not loading properly. So if I select countries with names starting with the letter >F, it is undefined because the entire file is not getting loaded. With countries having names starting with A-F, the code works fine. So I'm trying to reduce the number of cities associated with each country.